# BarSeries linewidth ignored on Shinobi

Tags: android, shinobi

I'm trying to set the width of the bars of a BarSeries with Shinobi.
Code's following:

```
DataAdapter<String, Double> da1 = new SimpleDataAdapter<String, Double>();
        da1.add(new DataPoint<String, Double>("q1", 1.0));
        da1.add(new DataPoint<String, Double>("q2", 3.0));
        da1.add(new DataPoint<String, Double>("q3", 4.5));
        da1.add(new DataPoint<String, Double>("q4", -2.5));
        BarSeries series1 = new BarSeries();
        series1.setDataAdapter(da1);
        BarSeriesStyle css1 = series1.getStyle();
        css1.setLineWidth(180.0f);
        css1.setAreaColor(Color.YELLOW);

        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        chart.setXAxis(xAxis);
        xAxis.getStyle().setInterSeriesPadding(0.2f);
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        chart.setYAxis(yAxis);
        yAxis.getStyle().setInterSeriesPadding(0.2f);

        chart.addSeries(series1);
```

What happens is that the line `css1.setLineWidth(180.0f);` is completely ignored. I can put `1.0f` or `1000.0f` and the lines are always  the same width no matter what.

What am I missing, or doing wrong? I'm using shinobi 1.5.1.

---

Edit: same goes with ColumnSeries:

```
ColumnSeries cs = new ColumnSeries();
    DataAdapter<Float, Integer> adapterAxis = new SimpleDataAdapter<Float, Integer>();
    adapterAxis.add(new DataPoint<Float, Integer>(0f, 3));
    cs.getStyle().setLineColor(Color.BLACK);
    cs.getStyle().setLineWidth(1f);
    cs.setDataAdapter(adapterAxis);
```

`1f` or `20f`, nothing changes.
        chart.addSeries(cs);

---

Edit: following Kai's answer.

I tried playing around with `setInterSeriesPadding`, but it doesn't do what I need in that if I approach `1.f` as padding value the bar will shrink, but if I set `0f` the bar will have a minimum height and the space between them will remain 'big'.

To be clearer: I have 4 bars at 0 to 4 on the Y axis with different X values. Each one is centered more or less on the Y value (not really, but not important right now). E.g. bar centered in 2 will go from ~1.8 to ~2.2 and bar centered in 3 will go from ~2.8 to to ~3.2. I want them thicker, so that they go from ~1.55 to ~2.45 and from ~2.55 to ~3.45. How do I do that?

---

Edit 2 (images):

Actual:

[image: actual result]

Desired (sorry for my lack of Paint skills, it was just a way to show that I want them thicker):
[image: desired result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refer to width of a bar series, I am going to assume you mean the height, i.e. measuring from the top to the bottom of the bar. I'd like to mention that the setLineWidth() method is not intended for this purpose, but in fact this method is used to style the line which is drawn around the edge of a bar (or column) to act as a border. As the value passed to this method is increased, the bars (or columns) remain the same size, but the line grows inward. Subsequently, a large number will give the appearance of no line, as the bar or column will have a line so thick that it fills the entire bar (or column).

If you wish to manipulate the height of the bars (or the width of the columns) you need to use the methods:

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiChartsAndroid/1.5.1/Premium/Normal/apidocs/docs/reference/com/shinobicontrols/charts/AxisStyle.html#setInterSeriesPadding(float)

and

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiChartsAndroid/1.5.1/Premium/Normal/apidocs/docs/reference/com/shinobicontrols/charts/AxisStyle.html#setInterSeriesSetPadding(float)

I hope that you find this information useful. Thanks and kind regards,

Kai.

EDIT:

Hello Stephen,

Thanks for the extra information.

So today I created a quick app, using your code to populate a Shinobi chart with data.

I did see the thin bars issue which you describe. I believe in order to correct this you also need to call the method Axis.setInterSeriesSetPadding(float).

Although when you use a single series in your chart it is not obvious, this method does affect the spacing between individual bars. By default there is a small spacing between bars if this method is not explicitly called.

Please remember also that these two methods expect a float value between 0 (no padding at all) and 1. I suggest you call both of these methods with a parameter of 0.0 and slowly increase the values until you achieve the appearance you wish. You should only need to call these 2 methods on your category axis, not the data axis.

Whilst building my app with your code I did notice that you use a bar series, but you have your category axis on the x axis. I found when I built my app it initially only displayed 3 bars as the first category ("q1") was rendered as having a zero data value. This is because categories are internally given an integer index, and so the first category is stored with a 0 index.

The typical way to use a bar series is to have the categories on the y axis and the data values on the x axis. I modified my app to use this configuration and I found all 4 bars showed correctly. Furthermore I was able to have a padding ranging from nothing, where the bars were butted up against each other, to a lot of padding where the bars appear thin.

I hope that this helps,

Thanks,

Kai.
Disclaimer: I work for ShinobiControls.

Comment: thanks for the clarification of what the method does. I tried the interSeriesPadding, but it's not enough, I'll update my question with more details.

Comment: I've updated with a couple of images of how it results now and how I'd like it to be, thanks

Comment: thanks for the update, i'll try that as soon as i can!

Comment: Hi Kai, it does work. I still have the problem when using multiple series, but that is a different question I guess. I'll mark your answer as accepted and open a new question. Thanks!